# Java server with concurrent chunking enabled

Tags: fine-uploader

I have been playing around with the Java server example:

https://github.com/FineUploader/server-examples/tree/master/java

Its working great with chunking enabled, however I don't believe it supports chunking with the concurrent:enabled feature turned on in the JS client. Is this feature working in the Java server? Is there any plans to get this to work? Additionally, if not, any quick tips as to where to add this feature into the example code? I would be happy to implement this if needed..

Cheers!

J

Comment: Stack overflow isn't designed for discussions. For feature requests and bug reports, please open up an issue in the respective GitHub project's issue tracker.

Comment: ok so I will take this a "No" this feature is not implemented in this example?

Comment: I was more asking for some pointers on either how to get it working, or some pointers on where/how to implement it in the  example.. Not asking for the feature to be built or that there is any bug in the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this feature working in the Java server?

Yes, this is fully functional with any server. The [Java example in the server-examples GitHub repository](https://github.com/FineUploader/server-examples/tree/master/java) does not have code to handle this for traditional endpoints, but concurrent chunking will work fine without any code changes when uploading to S3 or Azure.

> Is there any plans to get this to work?

No plans at the moment to update the traditional endpoint Java server example.

> any quick tips as to where to add this feature into the example code?

You can follow the implementation in [the Node.js example](https://github.com/FineUploader/server-examples/blob/master/nodejs/nodejs.js), along with [the concurrent chunking documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/concurrent-chunking.html).